# Chrome Extensions: Sharing Object References Between Injections of Content Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to save down an array of new DOM element objects via an injected Content Script, then read it back out again when running that same script again?

- `chrome.storage` does not work, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) (objects need to be JSON-ifiable)
- **Background**: My Content Script introduces some new formatting to a page (via new DOM elements). I need to undo that formatting next time the script runs, in order to apply clean new formatting.

Thank you.

Comment: What about assigning a unique classname to the newly created elements and check that classname upon new executions of the content script?

Comment: Thanks. You mean come up with a classname that no webpage in the world is, and never will be, using? Is that not a bit hard? I mean I could write a bunch of letters and words and hope that it is unique, but is that a good solution?

Comment: Yes. There is no absolute unique, but you can come up with a highly unlikely value, like the result of passing your e-mail address through a hash function, or your full name written in camelCase.

Comment: You can still, like I mentioned in one of your previous questions, store HTML code of the required elements as a string inside `chrome.storage`.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Thank you. Could you perhaps share a link with an example of how that is done, or alternatively post an answer? I tried to think through it, but not sure what to do.